# jQuery Ajax request fails with readyState:0 error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code (previously, it was a full $.ajax() call, but I simplified it to $.post() to elliminate possible misconfiguration, but it did not help):

```
$.post( "/ajax/login.php", { username: username, password: password }, function(data) {
    if (data.result === 'success') {
        $('#login').submit();
    } else {
        alert(data.message);
    }
}, "json").fail(function(event, jqXHR, settings){
    alert("An error occured. Please try again later. All we know: " + JSON.stringify(event) + " " + jqXHR + " " + settings + " " + exception);
});
```

So I get `{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText:"error"}`. IE9 with default settings, iPhone, iPad & Mac Safari browser and sometimes Chrome.

Besides, IE9 also hangs the browser for 60 seconds until the request times out and then displays the error message.

Sometimes IE9 goes through instantly without any problems.

As you can see, there is NO cross-domain request, as I am using relative path. Only way I was able to solve this is by using GET request. Which is terrible, as access.log on the server can store all the user passwords.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case, make sure you have nothing perturbating the execution of your ajax request, possibly terminating it too early and causing a readyState = 0 error.

You can do this by using `event.preventDefault()` in your function that starts the request.

For example :

```
function buttonClicked(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post(...);
}
```